# Object Editting in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React. I'm trying to edit this Object, but I can't create the right function to edit this object, I want to edit item in "isikolom".

My Object:

```
const [staffData, setStaffData] = useState<Object>({
    ["Uncatagorize"]: {
      namakolom: "Uncatagorize",
      isikolom: [
        {
          nama: "Evan Jovian",
          usia: "21",
          alamat: "Jln.Pontianak III no.32",
          kota: "Bandung",
          telepon: "082125439087",
          nomorKaryawan: "2301873560",
        },
        {
          nama: "Japri Supriyanto",
          usia: "31",
          alamat: "Jln.Kebon teh no.32",
          kota: "Bogor",
          telepon: "088172736464",
          nomorKaryawan: "2301873561",
        },
      ],
    }
  });
```

I wish I have function using hooks state to change "isiKolom".

Comment: Please provide some more details. What output are you receiving? Are there any errors? What is `setKolom`? Are you passing `setStaffData` as `setKolom`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mutate anything inside tempData now: push, pop, etc.

```
const [state,setState] = useState(object);

function updateIsiKolom(category, data){
  let tempData = JSON.strigify(JSON.parse(state));
  tempData[category].isiKolom = data
  setState(tempData);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a format how I would Do task like this.

```
cosnt [state,setState] = useState(object);

function changeObject(arg){
  let tempData = {...state};
  //now you have access to tempData change tempData and then change state.
  tempData.isikolom = [...tempData.isikolom,arg];
 //There is a problem with this that it take more memory.
  setState(tempData);
}
```

Comment: You show an anti-pattern which doesn't solve the problem

Comment: yes You are correct as I said This is a **FORMAT**   how would I do it.